# Form of a harmonic function

Tags: analysis, harmonic-functions

Given that $\phi(x^2+y^2)$ is harmonic, where $\phi: (0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, find the form of $\phi$.

I do not know what they mean by form nor could I find anything online... My book says that for the complex function $f(z)= (y^3-3x^2y)+i(-3xy^2+x^3+C)$ the form $f(z) = i(z^3+c)$ is easily verified and is suggested by taking $y=0$.

Thanks for any help, I will keep searching.

**EDIT** From the help I got below:

Taking $\psi(x,y) = \phi(x^2+y^2)$ then
\begin{align*}
  \psi_x =& \phi_x(x^2+y^2)2x \\
  \psi_xx =& 2\phi_x(x^2+y^2)+4x^2\phi_{xx}(x^2+y^2) \\
  \psi_y =& \phi_y(x^2+y^2)2y \\
  \psi_yy =& 2\phi_y(x^2+y^2) + 4y^2\phi_{yy}(x^2+y^2)
\end{align*}
I can add $\psi_{xx} + \psi_{yy} = 0$ but where does that get me? Where should I go from here?

**EDIT2:** Using Polar coordinates we know $x^2+y^2 = r^2$ so we have:
\begin{align*}
  \phi_r =& \phi_r(r^2)2r \\
  \phi_{rr} =& 2\phi_r(r^2) + 4r^2\phi_{rr}(r^2) \\
  \phi_\theta =& 0
\end{align*}

Comment: They probably just want you to consider the fact that $\psi_{xx}+\psi_{yy}=0$ where $\psi(x,y)=\phi(x^2+y^2)$. This should give you an equation for $\phi$.

Comment: Maybe it would help to think about this as $\phi(|z|^2)$ is harmonic. I want to say it's "radially harmonic".

Comment: Are you suggesting that I take the partial derivatives  to get expressions for $\phi_{xx}$ and $\phi_{yy}$?

Comment: Yes, or something of that form.

Comment: Could you give me a bigger hint, I'm going to post what I have now as an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Hint:* Note that $\phi$ is a function of one variable, hence $\psi_{xx} + \psi_{yy} = 0$ implies
$$4\phi'(x^2+y^2)+4(x^2+y^2)\phi''(x^2+y^2) = 0,$$
i.e.
$$\phi'(t)+t\phi''(t) = 0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: convert to polar coordinates.  The condition for $u(r,\theta)$ to be
harmonic is $u_{rr} + u_r/r + u_{\theta,\theta}/r^2 = 0$.

Alternatively, consider the map of $\mathbb C$ onto ${\mathbb C} \backslash \{0\}$ by $w \mapsto z = e^{w}$.  $u(z)$ is harmonic on ${\mathbb C} \backslash \{0\}$ if and only if $U(w) = u(e^{w})$ is harmonic on $\mathbb C$.  What harmonic functions of $w$ depend only on the real part of $w$?

Comment: To clarify, is $\psi = u$?

Comment: How does this relate back to form? I have some new expressions. I'll write them up in an edit.